# VB.NET Parallel For Each over Data Tables in a Data Set

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, dataset

I'm building code to test looping through the tables in a data set using a parallel for each loop, but I am getting an error.  The error is on the ForEach call throwing an overload resolution failed syntax error.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong in the following code:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dr As DataRow

ds.Tables.Add()
ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(String))
ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add("Col3", GetType(String))
ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add("Col4", GetType(String))

dr = ds.Tables(0).NewRow()
dr("Col1") = "Loaded"
dr("Col2") = "Col 2 Data"
dr("Col3") = "Col 3 Data"
dr("Col4") = "Col 4 Data"
ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr)

ds.Tables.Add()
ds.Tables(1).Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
ds.Tables(1).Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(String))
ds.Tables(1).Columns.Add("Col3", GetType(String))
ds.Tables(1).Columns.Add("Col4", GetType(String))

dr = ds.Tables(1).NewRow()
dr("Col1") = "Loaded"
dr("Col2") = "Col 2 Data"
dr("Col3") = "Col 3 Data"
dr("Col4") = "Col 4 Data"
ds.Tables(1).Rows.Add(dr)

Parallel.ForEach(
ds.Tables.Cast(Of DataTable),
Sub(table)
    ProcessTable(table)
End Sub
)
```

Comment: I appreciate the complete example. However it runs just fine when `ProcessTable(DataTable)` is empty. Can you share the definition of that method, as well as any overloads (which is seems is the error)?

Comment: Thank you very much, djv.  When I commented out the ProcessTable line, the error on the ForEach went away.  There is no definition yet for a method called ProcessTable... lol

I assumed that if there was an error inside the parallel sub, that the error would show on the line and not the ForEach call.  When I saw the error on the ForEach, I assumed there was an error on the syntax of the ForEach itself.

Comment: So this is what we call a typo :)

Comment: It means that I am just beginning my journey to understand parallel processing.

I have completed my test code and would like to post it here for anyone it might help, but it is too long for a comment.  How can I post it?

Comment: The actual error was just a typo, so would posting your code here for posterity actually help anyone? What I mean is, the code you have posted above is already issue-free assuming ProcessTable is defined, and it doesn't really matter what is inside it, as I have mentioned in my first comment. If I were you I'd just leave it as is - and FYI this question will be *closed* very soon once a third person votes for that, so I wouldn't worry about posting your test code

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as pointed out by djv, is that there is no problem with the code.

The compiler was complaining that the method, ProcessTable, did not exist.  The compiler was just throwing me off by putting the error on the line of the ForEach call instead of the ProcessTable method call.